# UiProgressView Custom with PaintCode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, viewcontroller, uiprogressview, paintcode

I'm doing several tests with drawing a PaintCode progressView implementing it within a custom UIView controller ...
The procedure is as you well know place a UIView object and change its class progressview in order to invoke the customization within the view in viewcontroller.

So far so good, my only problem is that when I go to compile the project I get always a gray circle or rectangle (depending on the size of the view included in the viewcontroller) that is going to superimpose my progressview personalized ...

I do not understand where I'm wrong also because the only code that I inserted is just a simple customization file ProgressView (subclass ProgressView). In view controller there is nothing ...

I followed the tutorial and 'this
http://www.raywenderlich.com/it/44556/paintcode-tutorial-progress-bar-custom

Do you know how to solve my problem? Thanks to all for future aid Rory.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //// General Declarations
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.416 green: 0.416 blue: 0.416 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.322 green: 0.322 blue: 0.322 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* shadowColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.2 green: 0.2 blue: 0.2 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* shadowColor3 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.671 green: 0.671 blue: 0.671 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* fillColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.247 green: 0.247 blue: 0.247 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* strokeColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.188 green: 0.188 blue: 0.188 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0 green: 0.886 blue: 0 alpha: 1];

    //// Gradient Declarations
    NSArray* outerRectGradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        (id)strokeColor.CGColor,
                                        (id)fillColor.CGColor, nil];
    CGFloat outerRectGradientLocations[] = {0, 1};
    CGGradientRef outerRectGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)outerRectGradientColors, outerRectGradientLocations);
    NSArray* gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               (id)strokeColor2.CGColor,
                               (id)fillColor2.CGColor, nil];
    CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0, 1};
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)gradientColors, gradientLocations);

    //// Shadow Declarations
    UIColor* darkShadow = shadowColor2;
    CGSize darkShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3.1, 3.1);
    CGFloat darkShadowBlurRadius = 5;
    UIColor* lightShadow = shadowColor3;
    CGSize lightShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3.1, 3.1);
    CGFloat lightShadowBlurRadius = 5;

    //// Frames
    CGRect progressIndicatorFrame = CGRectMake(-1, 0, 321, 47);

    //// Subframes
    CGRect group = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(progressIndicatorFrame) + 10, CGRectGetMinY(progressIndicatorFrame) + 9, CGRectGetWidth(progressIndicatorFrame) - 25, 20);
    CGRect activeProgressFrame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(group) + floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 0.00000 + 0.5), CGRectGetMinY(group) + floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 0.00000 + 0.5), floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 1.00000 + 0.5) - floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 0.00000 + 0.5), floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 1.00000 + 0.5) - floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 0.00000 + 0.5));

    //// Abstracted Attributes
    CGRect progressTrackActiveRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(activeProgressFrame) + 4, CGRectGetMinY(activeProgressFrame) + 5, CGRectGetWidth(activeProgressFrame) - 8, 10);

    //// Progress Bar
    {
        //// Border Drawing
        CGRect borderRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(progressIndicatorFrame) + 2, CGRectGetMinY(progressIndicatorFrame) + 3, CGRectGetWidth(progressIndicatorFrame) - 5, 34);
        UIBezierPath* borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: borderRect cornerRadius: 4];
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, darkShadowOffset, darkShadowBlurRadius, darkShadow.CGColor);
        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);
        [borderPath addClip];
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, outerRectGradient,
                                    CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(borderRect), CGRectGetMinY(borderRect)),
                                    CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(borderRect), CGRectGetMaxY(borderRect)),
                                    0);
        CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);

        ////// Border Inner Shadow
        CGRect borderBorderRect = CGRectInset([borderPath bounds], -lightShadowBlurRadius, -lightShadowBlurRadius);
        borderBorderRect = CGRectOffset(borderBorderRect, -lightShadowOffset.width, -lightShadowOffset.height);
        borderBorderRect = CGRectInset(CGRectUnion(borderBorderRect, [borderPath bounds]), -1, -1);

        UIBezierPath* borderNegativePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: borderBorderRect];
        [borderNegativePath appendPath: borderPath];
        borderNegativePath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        {
            CGFloat xOffset = lightShadowOffset.width + round(borderBorderRect.size.width);
            CGFloat yOffset = lightShadowOffset.height;
            CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context,
                                        CGSizeMake(xOffset + copysign(0.1, xOffset), yOffset + copysign(0.1, yOffset)),
                                        lightShadowBlurRadius,
                                        lightShadow.CGColor);

            [borderPath addClip];
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-round(borderBorderRect.size.width), 0);
            [borderNegativePath applyTransform: transform];
            [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
            [borderNegativePath fill];
        }
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        //// ProgressTrack Drawing
        CGRect progressTrackRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(progressIndicatorFrame) + 12, CGRectGetMinY(progressIndicatorFrame) + 12, CGRectGetWidth(progressIndicatorFrame) - 29, 14);
        UIBezierPath* progressTrackPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: progressTrackRect cornerRadius: 7];
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, lightShadowOffset, lightShadowBlurRadius, lightShadow.CGColor);
        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);
        [progressTrackPath addClip];
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient,
                                    CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(progressTrackRect), CGRectGetMinY(progressTrackRect)),
                                    CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(progressTrackRect), CGRectGetMaxY(progressTrackRect)),
                                    0);
        CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);

        ////// ProgressTrack Inner Shadow
        CGRect progressTrackBorderRect = CGRectInset([progressTrackPath bounds], -darkShadowBlurRadius, -darkShadowBlurRadius);
        progressTrackBorderRect = CGRectOffset(progressTrackBorderRect, -darkShadowOffset.width, -darkShadowOffset.height);
        progressTrackBorderRect = CGRectInset(CGRectUnion(progressTrackBorderRect, [progressTrackPath bounds]), -1, -1);

        UIBezierPath* progressTrackNegativePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: progressTrackBorderRect];
        [progressTrackNegativePath appendPath: progressTrackPath];
        progressTrackNegativePath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        {
            CGFloat xOffset = darkShadowOffset.width + round(progressTrackBorderRect.size.width);
            CGFloat yOffset = darkShadowOffset.height;
            CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context,
                                        CGSizeMake(xOffset + copysign(0.1, xOffset), yOffset + copysign(0.1, yOffset)),
                                        darkShadowBlurRadius,
                                        darkShadow.CGColor);

            [progressTrackPath addClip];
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-round(progressTrackBorderRect.size.width), 0);
            [progressTrackNegativePath applyTransform: transform];
            [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
            [progressTrackNegativePath fill];
        }
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        //// Group
        {
            //// ProgressTrackActive Drawing
            UIBezierPath* progressTrackActivePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: progressTrackActiveRect cornerRadius: 5];
            [color setFill];
            [progressTrackActivePath fill];
        }
    }

    //// Cleanup
    CGGradientRelease(outerRectGradient);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

Comment: @JuJoDi Please don’t use the cocoa tag for Cocoa Touch questions: use the cocoa-touch tag instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two things in that tutorial you haven't changed yet. 
This line

```
 //// Frames
CGRect progressIndicatorFrame = CGRectMake(-1, 0, 321, 47);
```

Should look like this

```
 //// Frames
CGRect progressIndicatorFrame = rect;
```

And this line

```
//// Abstracted Attributes
CGRect progressTrackActiveRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(activeProgressFrame) + 4, CGRectGetMinY(activeProgressFrame) + 5, CGRectGetWidth(activeProgressFrame) - 8, 10);
```

should look like this

```
//// Abstracted Attributes
CGRect progressTrackActiveRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(activeProgressFrame) + 4, CGRectGetMinY(activeProgressFrame) + 5, (CGRectGetWidth(activeProgressFrame) - 8) * self.progress, 10);
```

Also, if you're using iOS 7, you'll need to remove all subviews from your UIProgressView subclass. I'm using IB, so my initWithCoder: method looks like this:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {
        NSArray *subViews = self.subviews;
        for(UIView *view in subViews) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

If not, you'll have a default looking progress bar superimposed on your custom progress bar.